How to pass parameters to the remoteapp program
How to pass parameters to the remote app startup program.
I added a configuration with the alias test in the TSAppAllowList registry
Connecting to a remote application.
using C # can run normally, but I want to pass parameters to the application. What do I need to do?
// rc AxMsRdpClient11NotSafeForScripting
            rc.Name = "192.168.1.53";
            rc.UserName = "administrator"; 
            rc.Server = "192.168.1.53"; 
            rc.Height = rc.DesktopHeight = this.Height;
            rc.Width = rc.DesktopWidth = this.Width;
            rc.AdvancedSettings9.SmartSizing = true; 
            rc.RemoteProgram2.RemoteProgramMode = true; 
            rc.OnConnected += (o, e) =>
            {
                //but I want to pass parameters to the application
                ((ITSRemoteProgram)((IMsRdpClient9)rc.GetOcx()).RemoteProgram2).ServerStartProgram(@"||test", "", "", false, "", false); 
            }; 
            IMsTscNonScriptable securd = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rc.GetOcx();
            rc.AdvancedSettings9.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
            securd.ClearTextPassword = "123"; 
            rc.Connect(); 


I wrote this way, but it didn't work. The application on the server couldn't accept it.  ((ITSRemoteProgram)((IMsRdpClient9)rc.GetOcx()).RemoteProgram2).ServerStartProgram(@"||test", "", "", false, "paramvalue", false);
